# Redux middleware is half working but not fully cancelling action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have some simple middleware that is kind of working but also not working

basically I have a list of users and I am trying to delete one. and then sync it up with firebase. all is well.

I'm adding some middleware so that when a user deletes one it asks if you are sure? (just using a simple `alert` for now). if you click cancel, it doesn't delete. if you click ok it does

so far, that is working but because of my action creators it still carrying on and deleting the user. here is some code:

// click to delete user

```
  <button
    onClick={() =>
      this.props.deleteUserFromStoreThenUpdateFirebase(user)
    }
 >
```

calls this method
I think something funky is going on here, basically it shouldn't call the `deletedUserFromFirebase` method if I hit cancel

```
export const deleteUserFromStoreThenUpdateFirebase = user => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch(deleteUser(user)).then(() => {
      return deleteUserFromFirebase(user);
    })
  };
};


export const deleteUser = user => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: DELETE_USER, user: user, reqConfirm: true });
  };
};
```

middleware:

```
const confirmMiddleware = store => next => action => {
    if(action.reqConfirm){
      if(confirm('are you sure?')){
        next(action)
      }
    }
    else {
      next(action)
    }
}
```

Comment: To be on the safe side, could you consider having an action that will show a confirmation dialog and dispatching a delete action only when user clicks ok?

Comment: yeh that's exactly what I want. how do I do that? I was thinking of catching the promise and returning false or something?

Comment: You should probably use a custom dialog instead of `confirm` to have more control. Show the dialog when button is clicked, but don't dispatch anything yet. Only dispatch DELETE_USER  when user confirms that they indeed want that user to be deleted.

Comment: but I still think confirm can work? it's just when is getting called rather than confirm itself

Comment: @Aaaron any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**I also think that confirmation actions should be [only] role of the UI.**

Redux store can (should?) be treated like API - request (action) > response (changed state). Are you sending request to an API and waiting to confirmation message? It would be at least strange.

**But I see even more than some sense in this idea.** Centralised confirmation element can have a similiar role to toasts/snackbar messages.

**Problem #1**: There is a **strict** separation between UI and store logic - **you can't use middleware to show dialog**. But **you can change state which can used in UI to show confirmation dialog**.

**Problem #2**: There is no simple `if/then/return` chain of actions, **you have to buffer an action** and run it after confirmation (receiving 'confirm' action) or drop it on cancel. Yes, it can be done as middleware.

**IDEA**:
Action dispatched as requiring confirmation is saved in buffer. You can then change action type to `CONFIRM_SHOW` - state will be changed, props passed, modal dialog can be shown.

On `CONFIRM_OK` run buffered action, next steps will be common with `CONFIRM_CANCEL`: clear buffer and hide modal. It could be even one value - buffer can be a modal flag (empty - hide, defined - show) dervied in `mapStateToProps`.

To be fully usable there should be an option to pass custom confirmation message along with `reqConfirm`.